# Get index statistics information for tables referenced in a specific view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to amend the following script to point at just the indexes *associated* with a particular view `vw_foo`. Is this possible?

```
SELECT name AS index_name,
STATS_DATE(OBJECT_ID, index_id) AS StatsUpdated
FROM sys.indexes
```

---

**Edit**

When I say "associated" I mean the indexes on the underlying tables that are used to create the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly, it will be helpful for you -

```
SELECT 
      SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]) + '.' + o.name
    , s.name
    , statistics_update_date = STATS_DATE(o.[object_id], stats_id) 
FROM sys.objects o
JOIN sys.stats s ON o.[object_id] = s.[object_id]
WHERE o.[type] = 'V' AND o.name = 'vw_foo'

DECLARE @table_name SYSNAME
SELECT @table_name = 'dbo.vw_foo'
```

**EDITED**

> When I say "associated" I mean the indexes on the tables that are used
>   by the view

This query returns the list of the views where is used the specified table + shows additional info about the used index -

```
SELECT 
      o.table_name
    , b.view_name
    , i.name
    , stast_updates = STATS_DATE(i.[object_id], i.index_id)
    , dm_ius.last_user_seek
    , dm_ius.last_user_scan
    , dm_ius.last_user_lookup
    , dm_ius.last_user_update
    , dm_ius.user_updates
    , dm_ius.user_lookups
    , dm_ius.user_scans
    , dm_ius.user_seeks
FROM (
    SELECT
          table_name = s.name + '.' + o.name
        , o.[object_id]
    FROM sys.objects o
    JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
    WHERE o.[type] = 'U'
        AND s.name + '.' + o.name = @table_name
) o
JOIN sys.indexes i ON o.[object_id] = i.[object_id]
                  AND i.[type] > 0
                  AND i.is_disabled = 0
                  AND i.is_hypothetical = 0
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats dm_ius ON i.index_id = dm_ius.index_id AND dm_ius.[object_id] = i.[object_id]  
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT 
          view_name = r.referencing_schema_name + '.' + r.referencing_entity_name
        , r.referencing_id
    FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities (o.table_name, 'OBJECT') r
    JOIN sys.objects o2 ON r.referencing_id = o2.[object_id]
    WHERE o2.[type] = 'V'
) b
WHERE b.view_name IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: +1 for such a full answer. I don't have admin rights so `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` isn't accessible; but otherwise very useful

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers were probably heading towards checking the name in `sys.objects` but never do it. But there's no need to do so anyway, since the `OBJECT_ID()` function lets you get an `object_id` in a clean fashion:

```
SELECT name AS index_name,
STATS_DATE(OBJECT_ID, index_id) AS StatsUpdated
FROM sys.indexes
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('vw_foo')
```

Comment: +1 ...but is it possible to pull in the indexes on the tables that are used by the view?

Comment: @whytheq - you can use [`sys.sql_expression_dependencies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677315.aspx) to chase from view to base tables (possibly via other views, functions, etc). How much use the information is in a complex dependency chain, I'm not sure.

Comment: I could almost do with some sort of tutorials on querying these sys objects - I have a few random scripts but no sort of structure in my mind on where to start with these scripts?